# Validate multidimensional array using jQuery validate plugin

Tags: jquery, multidimensional-array, jquery-validate

I have created form like this :

```
<form>
    <div class='row user">
         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user[0][name]" placeholder="Enter speaker's name">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user[0][email]"  placeholder="Email">
         </div>
    </div>
    <button onclick="addMoreUser()" class="add-more">Add User</button>
</form>
```

On Clicking "Add User" button it will add one more div with class "user" and it's input as user[1][name] and user[1][email].

I want to validate email and name as required and email must be valid email format.
For validation the code goes like here:

```
 $('form').validate({
    rules : {
        "user[][name]" : {
            required: true
        },
        "user[][email]" : {
            email: true,
            required : true,
        },
    },
    messages :{
        "user[][name]" : {
            required: "Name is Mandatory"
        },
        "user[][email]" : {
            email: 'Email must be valid email address',
            required : 'Email is Mandatory',
        },
    }
});
```

Can anyone please help me how to validate such multidimensional array using validate plugin? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First select all `input` elements that start with `user`.  Use a jQuery `.filter()` to find all elements that end with `name` and `email`.  Then use a jQuery `.each()` along with the `.rules()` method to loop through and apply the rules.

```
var user = $('input[name^="user"]');

user.filter('input[name$="[name]"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules("add", {
        required: true,
        messages: {
            required: "Name is Mandatory"
        }
    });
});

user.filter('input[name$="[email]"]').each(function() {
    $(this).rules("add", {
        email: true,
        required: true,
        messages: {
            email: 'Email must be valid email address',
            required : 'Email is Mandatory',
        }
    });
});
```

**DEMO**:  [jsfiddle.net/upq6uk0h/](http://jsfiddle.net/upq6uk0h/)

Answer (score -1):

When targeting more than one element, you must also use the jQuery .each() method.

```
 $('.form-control').each(function () { 
    $(this).rules("add", {
        required: true
    });
});
```